# Touchable didn't work when wrapped in some View tag React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Hello guys so I'm trying to create a to do list app and I want to use TouchableOpacity for the task status, when the user press it the task status will change. But for some reason the Touchable tag didn't work. I think it's because of the view on Home.JS. Can anyone help me to resolve this error ?

Here's my code

Home.js:

```
        <View>
            <View>
                {taskItems.length > 0 ? (taskItems.map((item, index) => {
                       return (
                            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.taskWrapper} key={index} onPress={() => completeTask(index)}>
                                <Task text={item} /> 
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                       )
                    })) :

                    (
                        <View style={styles.noItemWrapper}>
                            <Text style={styles.noItem1}>There are no task</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.noItem2}>Make your first reminder</Text>
                        </View>
                    )
                }
            </View>

            <KeyboardAvoidingView 
                behavior={Platform.OS === "Android" ? "padding" : "height"}
                style = {styles.writeTaskContainer}
            >
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder={'Write your task'} value={task} onChangeText={text => setTask(text)}/>

                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleAddTask() }>
                    <View style={styles.ButtonWrapper}>
                        <Text style={styles.addText}>+</Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>

            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Task.js Code:

```
const Task = (props) => { 
  const[pressed, setPressed] = useState(false);
  const onPressHandler = () =>{
    setPressed(!pressed);
  };

    return (
        <View style={styles.wrapper}>
          <Text style={styles.taskList}>{props.text}</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity style={{ ...{backgroundColor: pressed ? 'green' : '#ff3126'}, ...styles.taskStatus }} onPress={() => onPressHandler()}>
        {pressed ?
            <Text style={styles.statusText} onPress={() => onPressHandler()}>Done</Text>
            :
            <Text style={styles.statusText} onPress={() => onPressHandler()}>On Going</Text>
        }
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to import TouchableOpacity from this:

```
import {TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

Sometimes TouchableOpacity doesn't work well with position: 'absolute'.